# Finding a pair of divisors in a set of $n+1$ integers

Tags: solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

I am trying to solve the below problem without using induction.

> Consider a set of $n+1$ positive integers, each less than or equal to $2n$. Show there must always exist a pair of integers in the set, one dividing the other.

Here is my attempt. I'm trying to "shortcut" the proof somewhat by invoking the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, which I believe to be valid.

> Let $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_{n+1}\}$ be the set of $n+1$ positive integers. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, we can write each $s_i = 2^{a_i} \cdot (2b_i - 1)$, uniquely, where $a_i \geq 0$, $b_i  >0$. Notice that each element of $s$ is less than or equal to $2n$, and there are exactly $n$ odd numbers less than or equal to $2n$. By the pigeonhole principle, there exists $k \neq j$ such that $2b_k - 1 = 2b_j - 1$. Without loss of generality, suppose $a_k > a_j$. (If $a_k = a_j$, then $s_k = s_j$, which contradicts the fact that $S$ contains $n+1$ distinct elements.) Then $2^{a_k} (2b_k - 1) > 2^{a_j} (2b_j - 1)$. In particular,
> $$
> 2^{a_j} (2b_j - 1) \cdot 2^{a_k - a_j} = 2^{a_k} (2b_j - 1) = 2a^k (2b_k - 1),  
> $$
> that is,
> $$
> s_j \cdot 2^{a_k - a_k} = s_k,
> $$
> so $s_j \mid s_k$.

Comment: +1 : to your question.  Nice presentation.  I agree with your analysis.  Actually, this is a dupe of a mathSE question, where the exact same approach as yours was used, so mathSE reviewers may wish to close/delete your question as a dupe, even though your question is a solution verification question.  Also, you have a typo: "...such that $2bk−1=2bj=1$" should be "...such that $2bk−1=2bj-1$"